# How to get my own IP address from a struct addrinfo

Tags: c, linux, sockets, ip

I am binding a socket to my address to listen to connections. To do this, I get my address information using `getaddrinfo()` syscall, which grants me an ip independent way of doing what I want. The problem is that the structs which this syscall returns have the ip address field all blank. For example:

```
struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
int sock;

memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

getaddrinfo(NULL, port, &hints, &servinfo)

for (p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next)
   if (p->ai_family == AF_INET6)
      break;

sock = socket(p->ai_family, p->sock_type, p->protocol);
bind(sock, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen)
```

In the code above. the `*p` variable should have some kind of information on an IPv6 address of my machine since the bind succeeds, but the field `p->ai_addr->sin6_addr` (assume this would work without a casting) is blank. How can I know exactly what address I will be using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The address is not blank - it is all zeroes, which is `0::0`.  This is the special wildcard address which means to bind to *all* local interfaces.

You should not *care* what address(es) your host has - this list might change at any time, including immediately after you check it.

Once you have a client connected, you can use `getsockname()` on the socket returned by `accept()` to determine which one of your local addresses that client connected to.

Comment: You might have to care if the machine is connected to multiple networks and you don't want to listen for connections from all of them.  In that scenario, you have to bind to the specific IP(s) you do want to listen on.

Comment: @RemyLebeau-TeamB: In which case you should obtain the IP(s) from the user, and supply them to `getaddrinfo()` in the `node` argument.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you bind to  `localhost` (i.e. IPV4 `127.0.0.1`) or to  `ip6-localhost` (i.e. IPV6 `::1`) if you want to listen to local connections only?

Otherwise, leave all zeroes in the address like @caf suggested.